# PostgreSQL - aggregating data by date from datetime field

Tags: postgresql, datetime

I have data over time for particular users and timestamp of the form 2013-11-23 16:00:00-05 - there's by minute by minute date for each user and corresponding usage value.

So the table has values: user_ID, localminute, usage.

I am trying to aggregate usage at a day wise level, what i did so far is below s but I was looking for an easier way to do it without creating the dummy column date_event:

```
alter table tablename add column date_event date
update table set date_event = date(localminute)
select sum(use), date_event from tablename group by date_event
```

My question is about how I can extract date from timestamp and aggregate in a single query. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just cast it to a date:

```
select sum(use), localminute::date 
from tablename 
group by localminute::date;
```

or using standard SQL:

```
select sum(use), cast(localminute as date) 
from tablename 
group by cast(localminute as date);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

it isn't actually called timestamp. I used dummy names here to understand the functionality. Changed it up in my question anyway in case someone comes across this. Thanks again!